# Clicking the button of listview is not fetching the corresponding textview value of that listview item

Tags: android, listview

Im having buttons for each items of listview. When the button is clicked, it has to fetch a value of corresponding listview item.

Following is my getView method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.pending_orders_fragment, null);
            vholder = new ViewHolder();
            vholder.mShippngRefNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shipment_ref_no_value);
            vholder.contact = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            vholder.mShippingStatus.setTag(position);

            view.setTag(vholder);
        } else
            vholder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        PendingOrdersDao item = listforview.get(position);


        vholder.mShippngRefNo.setText(item.getSipmentNo());
        vholder.contact.setOnClickListener(this.onClickListener);

        return view;
    }

    public void setOnButtonClickListener(final View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }
```

Im invoking the button as follows in my code..

```
adapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                                            TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.shipment_ref_no_value);
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),textView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                                    });
```

But Im getting null pointer exception while doing so.How can I sort this out?

Following is my logcat

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                    at com.vaighai.fragments.MyOrdersFragment$2$1.onClick(MyOrdersFragment.java:253)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
>                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)

UPDATED LOGCAT:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                               at

> com.vaighai.adapters.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:122)
>                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
>                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: i have posted the logcat

Comment: @user1241241 Can we have full code of your Adapter class with constructor. May be this `setOnClickListener(this.onClickListener);` creates problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably you forget this in your activity

```
class MainAct extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly set   setOnClickListener .so remove from your code

```
vholder.contact.setOnClickListener(this.onClickListener);
```

add the following code

```
    vholder.contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
        TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.shipment_ref_no_value);
        Toast.makeText(context,textView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
       });
```

Comment: Again Im getting the same NullPointerException

Comment: i have posted the full logcat

Answer (score 0):

just in your Toast message write:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),listforview.get((int)vholder.mShippingStatus.getTag()).getSipmentNo(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And outside of your if and else inside getView() method write:

```
vholder.mShippngRefNo.setTag(position);
```

Comment: I tried setting tag. What should i write on onClick?

Comment: Did you write setTag() statement outside of if and else? because setting tag inside if block in getview will only set tag when convertview is null. So for all time setting tag write it outside of your if else block like:
if(convertview == null){}
else{}
vholder.mShippngRefNo.setTag(position);